# Internet lost connection Webbrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have webrowser in app. I need to do something with webrowser when the internet connection is lost e.g. display MessageBox and when internet is again available reconnect to website. I find that can i use DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event, but when I 'm testing, the event is not firing. 
I tried use DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable, when navigating but this not have functionality that i want. I have testing in Nokia Lumia 710.

Here my simple code, i make him from example from msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new EventHandler(NetworkAvailabilityChanged);

```
    void NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkNotificationEventArgs e)
    {            
       string info = string.Empty;
       bool connection = false;
       bool disco = false;

        switch (e.NotificationType)
        {                    
            case NetworkNotificationType.InterfaceConnected:                    
                    connection = true;                        
                    break;

            case NetworkNotificationType.InterfaceDisconnected:                    
                    info = "Lost Internet";      
                    disco=true;                                      
                    break;

            case NetworkNotificationType.CharacteristicUpdate:                   
                   break;                                 
            default:                   
                   break;

        }
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
           if(disco)
            MessageBox.Show(info);

            if(connection)              
             webbrowser1.Navigate(site);                                         
        });
    }
```

I have question i check in phone that these methods IsCellularDataEnabled, IsNetworkAvailable, IsWiFiEnabled return true. I read somewhere that event NetworkAvailabilityChanged only work when is only one type of network is enable. Is this true?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the names of some of those bools

Comment: It's only example, the really problem is that the event is not firing e.g. when I turn off router.

Comment: @user1389188 - one of your variable names is somewhat offensive in American English.

Comment: Sorry for that. I dont know, I'm not good in English. I check and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this page it may help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged(v=vs.92).aspx you can take the information of disconnected from NetworkNotificationEventArgs argument as it says...

Comment: I'm using this link to write this code. My problem is that the event is not firing e.g. when I turn off router.

Comment: @user1389188 have you found the solution ,if yes, please help me i am facing same kind of problem.

Comment: I'm checking that the Internet is lost in navigationfailed event for webbrowser. When this event fired i'm checking with NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Method and then when is return false i display MessageBox with info that Internet is lost. Maybe is not good solution, but i cant to force to properly work of NetworkAvailabilityChanged event.